# How do I get information about connected bluetooth devices with cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, bluetooth, cordova-plugins

I'm working on a cordova project, and I want to use a plugin to get information about my connected Bluetooth devices.

I've tried using multiple cordova plugins, but when I use each of them I run a scan, and they don't appear to find any Bluetooth devices when I have a device connected.

I used this code which I got from [this plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ble) documentation

```
evothings.ble.startScan(
    function(device)
    {
        console.log('startScan found device named: ' + device.name);
    },
    function(errorCode)
    {
        console.log('startScan error: ' + errorCode);
    }
);
```

When I connected a Bluetooth device, and ran the scan I expect the connected device to show up, but nothing showed up.